# Jasmine clock tick & Firefox: failing to trigger a Q.delay method

Tags: javascript, jasmine, q

Lazy loading tests:

I am trying to build a test for Jasmine to test a method that uses [Q.delay](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).
To go around the 10 seconds wait i'm using Jasmine's [clock](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Clock):

```
jasmine.Clock.tick(10010);
```

This works on Chrome but does not work on Firefox. I saw that the delay method of Q utilized **setTimeout** so I can't see any reason for the different behaviors.

Any ideas why it fails on Firefox?

Comment: You can just run tests via phantomJS.

Comment: Yah mate, Jasmine runs the tests headlessly.

Answer (score 0):

With jasmine 2.0 and Q at the [v1 tag](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js), I'm able to run this spec:

```
describe("testing", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });

  it("should work", function() {
    var foo = null;
    Q.delay('hi', 10000).then(function(arg) {
      foo = arg;
    });
    jasmine.clock().tick(10010);
    expect(foo).toEqual('hi');
  });
});
```

With no problems in both chrome, firefox, and phantomjs. I'm not sure if this is because we've fixed this issue in 2.0 or if you have some more complicated spec, that I'm not replicating here.