# Q.delay not working with Q promise library and Jasmine clock?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine, q

I have a very basic Jasmine test using Q, and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm simply using the Jasmine mock clock and trying to use Q.delay, which I think uses setTimeout under the hood.

I had some more complex tests that involved calling `setTimeout()` from a Q promise's `then` handler, and that didn't seem to work either, but I thought this would make a simpler test case to post on Stack Overflow.

Here's my very simple test case:

```
  it('clock test', function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
    var foo = null;
    Q.delay('hi', 10000).then(function(arg) {
      console.log('foo');
      foo = arg;
    });
    jasmine.clock().tick(10010);
    expect(foo).toEqual('hi');
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });
```

(This test was based on the test case found in a similar SO question: [Jasmine clock tick & Firefox: failing to trigger a Q.delay method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126604/jasmine-clock-tick-firefox-failing-to-trigger-a-q-delay-method))

When I run the test, it fails saying `Expected null to equal 'hi'.` The `console.log` never even executes.

To see if the problem was with Q or something else, I tried adding a simple `setTimeout` call inside the spec:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("bar");
}, 10000);
```

This worked - `bar` was printed to the console after the call to `jasmine.clock().tick`.

After the Jasmine clock is uninstalled, the normal clock kicks in, and after waiting 10 seconds, then the `foo` gets printed out.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking it to do async in a sync way. Don't. Try using Jasmine's async instead and drop using the clock.

```
it('clock test', function(done) {
    var foo = null;
    Q.delay('hi', 10000).then(function(arg) {
      console.log('foo');
      foo = arg;
      expect(foo).toEqual('hi');
      done();
    });
  }, 15000);
```

Comment: I tried that, and the spec timed out: `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Then, again, once the jasmine clock was uninstalled, 10 seconds later, `foo` gets printed.

Comment: Well, sure, that works, but it takes the spec 10 seconds to run. I wanted to use Jasmine's mock clock so it wouldn't.

It should work. When you `install()` the Jasmine clock, it replaces the global functions like `setTimeout` and friends. Since `Q.delay` uses `setTimeout` under the hood, this should work. As soon as you `tick` the Jasmine clock past 10 seconds, it should trigger.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Probably Q is serious about the asynchrony guarantee given by in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.org/). So even when `setTimeout` executes earlier than expected, that is no reason to suddenly call `then` callbacks synchronously. It still will need to wait a tick after the promise is fulfilled.

An alternative explanation would be that `Q` took its private copy of `setTimout` during its module initialising, to prevent exactly such messing around with builtins. Instead of calling the global function, it would use its internal reference to the old function, and not be affected by `jasmine.clock()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can spyOn Q.delay and avoid having your test wait for the given delay:

```js
describe('Q.delay', function() {
    it('should call Q.delay', function(done) {
        spyOn(Q.makePromise.prototype, 'delay').and.returnValue(function() {
            return this;
        });
        Q('A resolve value').delay(3000).then(done);
        expect(Q.makePromise.prototype.delay).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and can help speed up tests with delays.  But it should be
`spyOn(Q.makePromise.prototype, 'delay').and.callFake(function() {
            return this;
        });`